# How to find/correct error in a path

Tags: bash, zsh, directory, path

It's often that a long path is mistyped or you get a log file entry that a path does not exist. Is there a command or shell function that navigates the path hierarchy until it finds a matching path?

The command line exchange could go like this:

```
$ ls /var/lib/my/supper/complicated/path
File or directory not found
$ fixpath /var/lib/my/supper/complicated/path
Found /var/lib/my
```

As a bonus feature, a similarity detection would be great:

```
$ fixpath /var/lib/my/supper/complicated/path
Found /var/lib/my
Did you mean /var/lib/my/super/complicated/path
```

Comment: What shell you use ? tcsh has auto correction available, otherwise just loop through the path, it's not hard to make a script

Answer (score 4):

```
 $ fixpath /home/user/docus/collection/unix/djakl/jfkdsl/dfjksld/fsdkl
Found /home/user/docus/collection/unix
 $ type fixpath
fixpath is a function
fixpath ()
{
    CURDIR="$PWD";
    DIR="$1";
    E=1;
    while [ $E -eq 1 ]; do
        cd "$DIR" 2> /dev/null && {
            E=0;
            echo Found "$DIR"
        } || {
            DIR="${DIR%/*}";
            DIR="${DIR:-/}"
        };
    done;
    cd "$CURDIR"
}
```

Similarity autocorrection most modern shells can do itself. At least bash and zsh do.

Answer (score 0):

The following shell function takes a pathname and determines the longest bit of it that actually exists. It does this by removing the last path element from the path until either the path is completely empty, or it corresponds to a file (or directory, or anything) that actually exists.

```
fixpath () (
    pathname="$1"

    while [ -n "$pathname" ] && [ ! -e "$pathname" ]; do
        pathname=${pathname%/*}
        case "$pathname" in
            */*) continue ;;
            *) [ -e "$pathname" ] || pathname=''
               break
        esac
    done

    printf 'Longest existing path in "%s" is "%s"\n' "$1" "$pathname"
)
```

The `case` statement is needed to terminate the loop in the case that `$pathname` does not contain a `/` (which means that it would not get modified by the variable substitution). This avoids an infinite loop under some circumstances.

Testing it:

```
$ fixpath /home/kk/blaha/123
Longest existing path in "/home/kk/blaha/123" is "/home/kk"

$ fixpath "$HOME/.profile"
Longest existing path in "/home/kk/.profile" is "/home/kk/.profile"

$ fixpath "n"
Longest existing path in "n" is ""
```